# Terminal transparency (urxvt) , Imagemagick, and X11 root window problem

Tags: command-line, transparency, x11, imagemagick

I use Ubuntu Natty, urxvt (with 256 colours), and Imagemagick (display -window root [...]) to set the root window to a picture. When I use the transparancy (-tr) option on urxvt, I get the Ubuntu X login screen background (The pink/purple one) and not the image that is currently on the root window. See picture at the bottom.

Note that the same problem exists if I run gnome-terminal and set its transparency.

I suspect that imagemagick is not drawing on the right X11 layer but I (and google) cannot figure out what the right option is.

Could the problem be with either the xorg configuration or with window composition?

[image]

*Cross post from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/324718/terminal-transparency-imagemagick-and-x11-root-window-problem) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20311/terminal-transparency-imagemagick-and-x11-root-window-problem) in the vain hope that someone will know the answer here.  If that offends, feel free to close.  And it seems that it was indeed a vain hope...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-sizing the images using convert into another directory and then using feh to display them.  Ugly but works.

Answer (score 1):

fake transparency {i.e. cropping the root image} is turned on with: +tr {and e.g.: -sh 20}
-tr turns off fake transparency
this is probably what youre doing, and probably not what you want to do

real transparency {i.e.: with a compositor} is done simply by setting the alpha of the window
e.g.:
xcompmgr or compiz or whatevs
urxvt -bg rgba:2000/2000/2000/dddd

see if xcompmgr and transset can do it for you; if not, nothing will likely work until you get that working